# HTML/JavaScript Expand buttons/divs when hovering over

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I know the onmouseover and onmouseout so that they can run a function when hovered over on when not being hovered over but I don't know how to make them expand. I have made dropdown boxes, but I can't get them to expand.
EX:

*123* [**Not Hovering**]
*123456789123* [**During Hover**]

I've Tried This:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="exp" onmouseover="over()" onmouseout="out()" style="background- color: #FFD700;width: 100px;height: 250px;">
            Expand Me!
        </p>
        <button onclick="run()">Run</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function over() {
                document.getElementById("exp").style.width = "250px";
            }
            function out() {
                document.getElementById("exp").style.width = "100px";
            }
        </script>
        <div id="x" style="background-color: #0FF">&emsp;</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

but I want it to come out and go back in slowly not instantly, and I'm sure there is a better way to do this because I don't want to go pixel by pixel to get it to go slower because that would lagg the webpage

Comment: show what you have tried? show html/javascript code

Comment: consider adding what you have tried?? what you expect to do?what do you mean by how to expand dropdowns?? are the custom or form select kinda?

Comment: The problem is on line 37.

Comment: @Donovan_D add the above comment into your question (click edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a CSS transition would be best for this, no JS needed.

```css
div {
  width: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 1s;
}

div:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>123456789123</div>
```

Comment: This works! No I know about onmouseout if js is needed but I want it to stop expanding and contract if they're no longer hovering over it and stop contracting and expand agian if they start hovering over it agian